# Passing original string PLUS matches when using gsub and block?

Tags: ruby, string

Rails fans are familiar with `params[:terms]` or a hash of 'things' passed to the controller collected form the url. E.g.:

```
params
=> {"term"=>"Warren Buffet",
    "controller"=>"search",
    "format"=>"json",
    "action"=>"index"}
```

If I want to use "Warren Buffet", "Warren" and "Buffet" in the code below, does anyone know which method I should be using instead?  `gsub` is close, but it takes each match and not the original string too. Unless I'm doing it wrong, which is totally possible:

```
@potential_investors = []
params[:term].gsub(/(\w{1,})/) do |term|
  @potential_investors << User.where(:investor => true)
  .order('first_name ASC, last_name ASC')
  .search_potential_investors(term)
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Don't you just want to split on spaces and include the original term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
s = "Filthy Rich"
s.split(" ").push(s)
>> ["Filthy", "Rich", "Filthy Rich"]
```

Or with `scan` if you prefer to use the regexp instead:

```
s.scan(/\w+/).push(s)
>> ["Filthy", "Rich", "Filthy Rich"]
```

Comment: I see what you are doing there. nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
params["term"].gsub(/(\w{1,})/)
```

returns an enumerator. You could convert it to an array and append the original term to it:

```
ary = params["term"].gsub(/(\w{1,})/).to_a + [params["term"]]
```

then process it:

```
ary.each do |term|
...
```

Comment: Very saucy my man (or woman) seph.  Good use of to_a and for thinking that way as well. I'll let this question simmer a bit more before I pick the winner.